# gcc how to include multiple header file at compile time for shared object

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to compile a .so file from a .a file and a .h file and a source file
.cpp

.so-output, shared library
.a-static library to use
.h-header file for the API
.cpp-source file
/include - Python dev package headers

When I first tried

```
gcc -fPIC pyOkHound.cpp -L ./PhraseSpotterAPI.h ./libPhraseSpotter.a -shared -o OkHound.so
```

gcc throws pyOkHound.cpp:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
which make sense because my source file needs Python.h

Then when I include the python lib

```
gcc -fPIC pyOkHound.cpp -L ./include/*.* ./PhraseSpotterAPI.h ./libPhraseSpotter.a -shared -o OkHound.so
```

it throws 
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.
I tried -l and -L to include the header files from python dev but it throws the same thing. 
However I do not think the -include is the right one to use since the header file is for the API not the source code.

how to include multiple header file at compile time for shared object?
I follow the -I flag also here https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html
    gcc -c -fPIC pyOkHound.cpp -I./include -shared -o OkHound.so

Comment: The `-L` flag is for libraries, not header files, and is supposed to be used with *directories*, not *files*. Similarly, `-I` is also intended for use with a directory containing header files. Usually you would include the file names of the header files in the `.cpp` file, and the directories you find those headers in with `-I` in the compiler flag. You need the `-I` before *each* directory, not just a single one.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try